# Twilo python Flask passing parameter

Tags: python, flask, twilio

I have an app with python which works but I like to pass the result of speech recognition to the caller I dont know how, I have tried everything. I even tried to set lastRes to global variable by declaring it on top it is not working

```
lastRes = ""
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/voice", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def voice():
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  resp.say("What is your name?")
  print ("1---------------")
  resp.gather(input='speech', timeout="3", action='/gather', method='POST')
  #resp.append(gather)
  print ("2---------------")
  return str(resp)

@app.route("/mainFlow", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainFlow():
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  resp.say("We are done?")
  print("5--------------->" + str(lastRes))
  return str(resp)

@app.route("/gather", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  print("3---------------")
  lastRes = request.values.get("SpeechResult", "")
  print("4--------------->" + str(lastRes))
  resp.redirect('/mainFlow')
  return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  lastRes = ""
  app.run(debug=True)
```

How can I pass lastRes to the routine /mainFlow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, I would ask why you are trying to redirect before you use the result. You already have the speech result in your `/gather` endpoint, why not respond then? Like this:

```
@app.route("/gather", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  lastRes = request.values.get("SpeechResult", "")
  resp.say('Thank you ' + lastRes + '.')
  resp.redirect('/mainFlow')
  return str(resp)
```

This response will say "Thank you" and the speech result before then redirecting to the main flow.

Alternatively, you are working with URLs here. You could set the response as a URL parameter, like this:

```
import urllib

@app.route("/gather", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  SpeechResult = request.values.get("SpeechResult", "")
  params = urllib.urlencode({"SpeechResult": SpeechResult})
  resp.redirect('/mainFlow?' + params)
  return str(resp)
```

Then you can use the `SpeechResult` in `mainFlow` like:

```
@app.route("/mainFlow", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainFlow():
  SpeechResult = request.args.get('SpeechResult')
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  resp.say("We are done? " + SpeechResult)
  return str(resp)
```

Finally, you could set the SpeechResult in the session as that is maintained over the course of a call too.

```
from flask import Flask, session, request

@app.route("/gather", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  session['SpeechResult'] = request.values.get("SpeechResult", "")
  resp.redirect('/mainFlow')
  return str(resp)

@app.route("/mainFlow", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainFlow():
  SpeechResult = session['SpeechResult']
  resp = VoiceResponse()
  resp.say("We are done? " + SpeechResult)
  return str(resp)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: I get undefined for session & params, where are session and params defined?

Comment: IN another words, params is defined in --> params = urllib.urlencode({"SpeechResult": SpeechResult})
  resp.redirect('/mainFlow?' + params)    how can I retrieve them in /mainFlow?      Also how can I access a global variable throughout all apps? For example I have testData which I get all my info in a csv file. How can I access them without having to keep opening a csv file in each app.  I tried making it global but it is not recognized in  each app. I also tried using class but twilo /voice doesnt run with self.voice

Comment: Apologies, I left a `params` in the last example from the previous one. Edited that out of my answer now. You also need to import `session` to use it. Add `session` to your import line at the top of your file that includes `Flask` as well. (`from flask import Flask, session`)

Comment: For your other questions, global variables are not the best idea for managing data in your application. If you have a bunch of different apps, then each app should open and use that CSV data separately. I tried to answer your class based question yesterday too, but I'm not sure that is going to solve that problem for you.